# How to set up input value in hash?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, url-routing, sammy.js

```
 self.search = function() {
        searchRes = $('#search_field').val();
        location.hash = "search" + "/" + searchRes;
    };     
 Sammy(function () {
                    this.get('#search',':searchRes', function() {
                    this.param.searchRes = $('#search_field').val();
                        $('.inside').each(function() {
                            console.log(this.params);
                            if ($(this).text().search($('#search_field').val()) == -1) {
                                $(this).parent().addClass('blind');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }).run();
```

I set up input value in the url, but I can't get the hash, which I need, to pass through the `get` function. I get an error like this:

> /#search/resultError {message: "404 Not Found get /#search/result"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to the [SammyJS docs](http://sammyjs.org/docs/routes) your route have to be defined as follow :

```
this.get('#/search/:searchRes', function() { 
    var searchRes= this.params['searchRes'];    
});
```

As you can fetch the search criteria from the param property I suggest to use this sample :

```
var searchRes = this.params['searchRes'];
```

The SammyJS object provides an [redirect](http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/0.7.4/Sammy.EventContext._methods_.redirect) method.

```
self.search = function() {
    searchRes = $('#search_field').val();
    app.redirect("#/search" + "/" + searchRes;);          
};
```

I hope it helps.